# Android Display information on LockScreen

Tags: android, lockscreen

Is it possible to Display Information on the lock screen from an Android application.
I came across a few Apps which allow you to display Email and Calendar information on the screen but could not find which API to use for achieving the same.

[image]

Comment: kindly share links the links to such apps . i think i know how they work , but we need to look at their permissions to know for sure.

Comment: @androiddeveloper https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noamwolf.android.androidfound

Comment: ahh.. There i see the permissions too :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android 4.2 [supports app widgets on the lockscreen](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen).

Comment: am sorry but this is out of context. Have you worked on the new SupportMapFragment ? incase you have please need your assistance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764266/android-supportmapfragment-exception-error

Comment: @HarshaMV: Android 4.0(?) added support for music players to have basic controls (play/pause/stop). Nothing before that, at least that was officially supported.

Comment: thank you. i guess an alternative lockscreen is the only way to go :D

Answer (score 2):

according to the [app you've mentioned](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noamwolf.android.androidfound) (which has very poor description and quite low rating) , i suspect they disable the keyguard (the default lock screen) each time they get the event of power off (or on) .

maybe the activity that they are using has a transparent background and is above the normal lock screen .

there are many similar apps , such as "widget Locker" ,"magic Locker" and "quick Launch" , all do about the same thing to replace the keyguard . most of them also have the ability to replace the launcher (but will still show the launcher of the user, of course) , for smoother experience .

does the screenshot belong to the app you've mentioned , or to something you wish to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

You can learn how it can be done if you look at the sources of open source project [contact owner](http://code.google.com/p/contactowner/) that adds a message to the lock screen, too.