# Adding Google maps v2 to my android app Programmatically with fragments

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

hi am playing around with fragments and Google maps and for some reason my map wont display,
I am using fragments with tabs and I want to add a map Programmatically with to one of the tabs.

Please what am I doing wrong:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener, OnClickListener {

/**
 * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
 * current tab position.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";
private SlidingMenu menu;

private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private static int lng = 0;
private static int lat = 0;





String display = "";
ProgressDialog pDialog;
ProgressDialog pDialog2;
GooglePlaces googlePlaces;
Foursquare foursquare;
PlacesList nearPlaces;
ArrayList<FsqVenue> nearbylist;
String types;
String Message;
Foursquare fsq;
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
ConnectionDetector cd;
GPSTracker gps;
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
LayoutInflater inflater;
RelativeLayout rlayout;
ListView listview;
Location location;
TextView myTitleText;
ImageView myTitleImage;
// static Context context;
public static Context appContext;

String catId = null;

int minlat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int minlong = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxlat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int maxlong = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

public static String KEY_REFRENCE = "refrence";
public static String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static String KEY_VICINITY = "vivinity";
public static String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";

Foursquare NearbyList = new Foursquare();

public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placesListItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
static List<Float> myLat = new ArrayList<Float>();
static List<Float> myLng = new ArrayList<Float>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    /*getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.window_title_single_item);*/
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, new SampleListFragment())
    .commit();

    // Set up the action bar to show tabs.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("MAP")
            .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("List")
            .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("AR")
            .setTabListener(this));
    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);

    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.behind_main);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
    if (!isInternetPresent) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);

        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // creating GPS Class object
    gps = new GPSTracker(this);

    // check if GPS location can get
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        Log.d("Your Location", "latitude:" + gps.getLatitude()
                + ", longitude: " + gps.getLongitude());
    } else {
        // Can't get user's current location
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "GPS Status",
                "Couldn't get location information. Please enable GPS",
                false);

        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    latitude = gps.getLatitude();
    longitude = gps.getLongitude();
    lng = (int) (longitude * 1E6);
    lat = (int) (latitude * 1E6);
    location = gps.getLocation();


    Button pointOfIntrest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.point_of_intrest);
    Button cloth = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clothing);
    Button sports = (Button) findViewById(R.id.atletics);
    Button nightlife = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nightlifespot);
    Button spirt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spritual);
    Button medic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.medic3);
    Button university = (Button) findViewById(R.id.university);
    Button hotel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lodging);
    Button atm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.banks);
    Button eat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.food);

    pointOfIntrest.setOnClickListener(this);
    cloth.setOnClickListener(this);
    sports.setOnClickListener(this);
    nightlife.setOnClickListener(this);
    spirt.setOnClickListener(this);
    medic.setOnClickListener(this);
    university.setOnClickListener(this);
    hotel.setOnClickListener(this);
    atm.setOnClickListener(this);
    eat.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Restore the previously serialized current tab position.
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Serialize the current tab position.
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar()
            .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, show the tab contents in the
    // container view.

    if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
        Fragment mMapFragment = new MapDisplayFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(MapDisplayFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER,
                89);
        ((Fragment) mMapFragment).setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, mMapFragment).commit();
    }

    if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
        Fragment mListFragment = new ListDispalyFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(MapDisplayFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER,
                49);
        mListFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, mListFragment).commit();
    }

    if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
        Fragment mMapFragment = new MapDisplayFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(MapDisplayFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER,
                59);
        mMapFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, mMapFragment).commit();
    }



}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    //fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.point_of_intrest:

        catId = "4d4b7104d754a06370d81259";
        if (myTitleText != null) {
            myTitleText.setText("Arts & Entertainment");
        }

        if (myTitleImage != null) {
            myTitleImage.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
        }

        menu.toggle();
        new LoadPlaces().execute();

        break;

    case R.id.clothing:

        types = "zoo|museum|amusement_park|city_hall|casino|aquarium|shopping_mall|university|spa";
        catId = "4d4b7105d754a06378d81259";
        if (myTitleText != null) {
            myTitleText.setText("Clothing Stores");
        }

        if (myTitleImage != null) {
            myTitleImage.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
        }

        menu.toggle();
        new LoadPlaces().execute();
        break;

    case R.id.atletics:

        types = "zoo|museum|amusement_park|city_hall|casino|aquarium|shopping_mall|university|spa";
        catId = "4d4b7105d754a06377d81259";
        if (myTitleText != null) {
            myTitleText.setText("Recreation& Outdoors");
        }

        if (myTitleImage != null) {
            myTitleImage.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

        }

        menu.toggle();
        new LoadPlaces().execute();
        break;

    case R.id.nightlifespot:

        catId = "4d4b7105d754a06376d81259";

        if (myTitleText != null) {
            myTitleText.setText("Nightlife Spots");

        }

        if (myTitleImage != null) {
            myTitleImage.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

        }

        menu.toggle();
        new LoadPlaces().execute();
        break;

    case R.id.spritual:

        catId = "4bf58dd8d48988d131941735";
        if (myTitleText != null) {
            myTitleText.setText("Spiritual Centers");

        }
        if (myTitleImage != null) {
            myTitleImage.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

        }

        menu.toggle();
        new LoadPlaces().execute();

        break;

    case R.id.medic3:

        catId = "4bf58dd8d48988d104941735";
        if (myTitleText != null) {
            myTitleText.setText("Medical Centers");

        }
        if (myTitleImage != null) {
            myTitleImage.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

        }

        menu.toggle();
        new LoadPlaces().execute();

        break;

    case R.id.university:

        catId = "4d4b7105d754a06372d81259";

        if (myTitleText != null) {
            myTitleText.setText("College & University");

        }

        if (myTitleImage != null) {
            myTitleImage.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

        }

        menu.toggle();
        new LoadPlaces().execute();
        break;

    case R.id.lodging:

        catId = "4bf58dd8d48988d1fa931735";

        if (myTitleText != null) {
            myTitleText.setText("Hotels");

        }

        if (myTitleImage != null) {
            myTitleImage.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

        }

        menu.toggle();
        new LoadPlaces().execute();
        break;

    case R.id.banks:

        catId = "4bf58dd8d48988d10a951735";

        if (myTitleText != null) {
            myTitleText.setText("Banks & ATMs");

        }

        if (myTitleImage != null) {
            myTitleImage.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

        }

        menu.toggle();
        new LoadPlaces().execute();
        break;

    case R.id.food:

        catId = "4d4b7105d754a06374d81259";

        if (myTitleText != null) {
            myTitleText.setText("Food");

        }

        if (myTitleImage != null) {
            myTitleImage.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

        }

        menu.toggle();
        new LoadPlaces().execute();
        break;

    }

}




private void validate(int size) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (size != 0) {
        for (FsqVenue item : nearbylist) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // System.out.print("match");
            map.put(KEY_REFRENCE, item.id);
            map.put(KEY_NAME, item.name);
            map.put(KEY_CATEGORY, item.type);
            myLat.add((float) item.location.getLatitude());
            myLng.add((float) item.location.getLongitude());
            Log.d("categories-match", String.valueOf(item.verified));
            placesListItems.add(map);

        }

    }




}

class LoadPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(Html
                .fromHtml("<b>Search</b><br/>Loading Places......"));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();
        foursquare = new Foursquare();

        try {
            // double radius = 10000;
            // NearbyList = foursquare.getNearby(latitude, longitude);
            // NearbyList.getNearby(latitude, longitude);
            nearbylist = foursquare.getNearby(latitude, longitude, catId);
            // int size = nearbylist.size();
            // System.out.print(size);
            // nearPlaces =
            // googlePlaces.search((double)gps.getLatitude(),(double)gps.getLongitude(),
            // radius, types);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("error" + e);
        }
        try {
            validate(nearbylist.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

        /*mapFrag = new MapDispalyFragment(location, placesListItems, myLat,
                myLng);

        mAdapter = new MyAdpater(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
         */
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

            }

        });

    }
}
```

}

my map Fragment activity
    public class MapDisplayFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

```
public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
private static final String MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG = "map";
private GoogleMap mMap;
private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

/*
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);

        // We only create a fragment if it doesn't already exist.
        if (mMapFragment == null) {
            // To programmatically add the map, we first create a SupportMapFragment.
            mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();

            // Then we add it using a FragmentTransaction.
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, mMapFragment, MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        // We can't be guaranteed that the map is available because Google Play services might
        // not be available.
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

*/  
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    Log.d("OnResume View" , "Sucess");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    /*TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
            ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));*/

    mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);

    // We only create a fragment if it doesn't already exist.
    if (mMapFragment == null) {
        // To programmatically add the map, we first create a SupportMapFragment.
        mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();

        // Then we add it using a FragmentTransaction.
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, mMapFragment, MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        mMapFragment.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d("OnCreate View" , "Sucess");
    }

    // We can't be guaranteed that the map is available because Google Play services might
    // not be available.
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    return null;
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));

}
```

}

My Log msg

```
01-21 21:12:38.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8924): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 21:12:38.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8924): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.reddotiantired/com.example.reddotiantired.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 21:12:38.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
01-21 21:12:38.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2492)
01-21 21:12:38.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1997)
01-21 21:12:38.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-21 21:12:38.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
01-21 21:12:38.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 21:12:38.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 21:12:38.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
01-21 21:12:38.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 21:12:38.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 21:12:38.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8924):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this post:

[Subclassing SupportMapFragment results in a NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725056/subclassing-supportmapfragment-results-in-a-nullpointerexception)

That did the trick for me.